# How can I determine how an Import/Export format works?

Tags: export, import, undocumented

Questions abound on the MSE about how to get a certain import / export feature to work as desired. For instance, here's one that popped up recently: [How can I standardize the coordinate origin for exported/imported outlines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164676/38205)

Generally this requires digging into the actual source data. So how can I do that? Even if I look in the `Names` (e.g. `` Names["*`*Export*PDF*", IgnoreCase -> True] ``) I find that the functions aren't loaded until I use them (which I may not want to do) and it's not entirely clear how to get them to load otherwise.

So how can I look at how these types of import / export formats are actually implemented.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a companion post to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164121/38205) and I'll make use of the scrapers I set up there.

Looking at the PDF case, we can scrape it's export data like so;

```
getFormatExportData["PDF"]

{"FormatName" -> "PDF", "DocumentedElements" -> None, 
 "Function" -> System`Convert`PDFDump`ExportPDF, 
 "HiddenElements" -> None, "Options" -> {"AllowRasterization"}, 
 "Sources" -> "Convert`PDF`", "BinaryFormat" -> True, 
 "File" -> 
  "/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Formats/PDF/Export.m"}
```

And we see this odd `"Sources"` element which maps to a context that can't be loaded with `Get` or `Needs`:

```
<< Convert`PDF`

Get::noopen: Cannot open Convert`PDF`.

$Failed
```

Digging further though into `` ImportExport`RegisterExport `` we find a curious function called `installExport` which later calls a function `installSource`. This is really just a forked `Get` for the different `"Sources"` types, which generally just means call `Get` on the package found on the `` System`ConvertersDump`$PackagePath ``.

This is the key function for us, as calling:

```
System`ConvertersDump`installSource["Convert`PDF`", Automatic];
```

causes our export function to get loaded:

```
System`Convert`PDFDump`ExportPDF // DownValues // Length

4
```

And then we can start to dig, which shows us two interesting things:

First, PDF export really just goes through the FE. In essence it calls:

```
First@FrontEndExecute@
  ExportPacket[
   System`ConvertersDump`createVectorExportPacketExpr[expr, opts],
   file,
    "ConversionOptions" -> attachments
   ]
```

Second, we can figure out what some of those `opts` can be by looking at `` System`Convert`PDFDump`getOptions ``. For example, we can control the `"OpacityRenderingMethod"`, `"RasterizationResolution"`, and `"VertexColorRenderingMethod"` directly in the `Export` call.

Unfortunately, what these values can be is unclear, as this is pulled directly from the FE, but it gives a sense of how you can spelunk these I/E functions

Comment: You may be interested in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnExportConverter.html and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html